# Linux linking a shared object

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld

I am linking an so, that depends on libmxml.so. However I have no rights install libmxml.so.

So thats what I am doing

```
gcc -shared -m32 -o ServiceProvider.so ServiceProvider.o -L ../../../../system/addonlibs/ -lmxml -lpthread
```

ldd shows me

```
ldd ServiceProvider.so 
    libmxml.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x40026000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x40046000)
```

the second try was

```
gcc -shared -m32 -o ServiceProvider.so ServiceProvider.o ../../../../system/addonlibs/libmxml.so -lpthread
```

and still ldd shows me

```
ldd ServiceProvider.so 
    libmxml.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x40026000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x40046000)
```

Consequently, ldd does not find the library, since I only have "libmxml.so", but no "libmxml.so.1". How do I get rid of this ".1" suffix? Why is it comming?

Comment: Do you actually have a shared library for libmxml, or is it a static library?

Comment: it is a shared library, I do have the libmxml.so from the build

Comment: no, i may not edit /lib -> no root rights

Comment: You can add the path of "libmxml.so" to "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".

Comment: Do you actually mean LIBRARY_PATH? Since I have compile-problems.

Comment: It's not a compile time problem. `ldd` shows you what the loader thinks should be loaded - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the one you want. Try it...

Comment: it does not help, since it searches for "libmxml.so.1", but i have only "libmxml.so" in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I am wondering, where this ".1" is coming from

Comment: In this case, just rename `libmxml.so` to `libmxml.so.1`, or make a symlink. Take a look at `/usr/lib`. You will see that it is a common practice.

Comment: Yes, thats how i solved it, but I'd know where .1 is coming from, is it kinda compiled into the .so file as 'soname'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you link with a dynamic library, you should not do :

```
gcc -shared -m32 -o ServiceProvider.so ServiceProvider.o ../../../../system/addonlibs/libmxml.so -lpthread
```

Instead, make sure that `/yourpath/system/addonlibs` (you should use the full path instead of a relative one) is in you `LIBRARY_PATH`. Then change you link command.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/yourpath/system/addonlibs:$LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -shared -m32 -o ServiceProvider.so ServiceProvider.o -lmxml -lpthread
```

You can also write that:

```
gcc -shared -m32 -o ServiceProvider.so ServiceProvider.o -L/yourpath/system/addonlibs -lmxml -lpthread
```

However, to run your program, you will need to have your library path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you have issues with `.so`and `.so.1` stuff, then rename your .so to .so.1 and make a symlink from `.so.1` to `.so`.

**Edit:**

If you do `objdump -p libmxml.so | grep SONAME` you will probably get `libmxml.so.1`.
It is where you get the `libmxml.so.1` identifier.

Comment: Or individually with `-l` option like so : `-l/yourpath/system/addonlibs/libmxml.so.1`

Comment: are you sure about export LD_LIBRARY_PATH? I'd guess it is just LIBRARY_PATH. You did not answer the question about ".so.1"

Comment: Edited my answer (see the `objdump` line at the end).

Comment: yea! thats it, if you replace LD_LIBRARY_PATH by LIBRARY_PATH, I will accept the answer!

Comment: Yes you are correct. `LIBRARY_PATH`is for the linker, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for.... `ld`. Will fix it. Thanks.